# I am gettin an error when try to generate android or ios build of ionic project

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have project build in ionic

I run the following command

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova platform add android
```

when I run them on my project folder I got the error in the following screenshot

[image]

I have tried to delete node_modules folder and run npm install command again but this does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

`add platform ios` need xcode

so

`add platform android` you need Android Studio

Comment: I have both android studio and xcode on my machine

Comment: when you run ` ionic cordova platform add android `
and run ` ionic cordova platform add ios`  got the same error ??

Comment: your project > platforms 
is have **ios** folder?